# Can the constructor call of an anonymous class have arguments

Tags: java, constructor

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread myThread = new Thread("YOYO") {
        public void run() {
            Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
            System.out.println(t.getName());
        }
    };

    myThread.start();
}
```

Can anyone explain what kind of feature the curly bracket code block that is next to the callling of the thread class contructor`new Thread("YOYO")`? As far as I know, it should not be Anonymous Classes because if it is Anonymous Class, the bracket next to `Thread` should be empty `()` instead of `("YOYO")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#syntax-of-anonymous-classes):

> The anonymous class expression consists of the following:
>
> 1. The new operator
> 2. The name of an interface to implement or a class to extend. In this example, the anonymous class is implementing the interface HelloWorld.
> 3. **Parentheses that contain the arguments to a constructor, just like a normal class instance creation expression.** Note: When you implement
>      an interface, there is no constructor, so you use an empty pair of
>      parentheses, as in this example.
> 4. A body, which is a class declaration body. More specifically, in the body, method declarations are allowed but statements are not.

`Thread` is a class, and it contains a [constructor with a `String` parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.String)), so, this is a valid anonymous class expression.

Comment: It might be worth adding that you could call it without the string, since there is [a no-arg constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread()) too.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I suppose, *"arguments to the constructor"* assumes, that there may be empty list of arguments. Good catch, though :)

Comment: @soon: According to the Java docs, so my above statement is that: calling the constructor of the Thread class with `public Thread(@NotNull java.lang.String name)`, and then extend the Thread class and finally override the superclass(i.e the Thread class)'s run method

Comment: @bufferoverflow76, I'm not sure if could explain the low-level way of creation an object of anonymous class, however, on the high level your statement may look like *"anonymous class expression firstly creates new type based on `Thread` with `run` method overriden, and then creates an instance of the new class. Called constructor delegated to the `Thread` as well"*.

Answer (score 3):

It is an anonymous inner class..

"YOYO" is not a name, it's just an argument you pass to the constructor, that is all.